# Bicep log analytics re-deployment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

All resources on bicep works fine. However, LAW errors out on resource plan conflict upon redeployment.

Status Message: Resource plan can not be changed for Resource id:
At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. "Resource plan cannot be    changed for Resource id:
   Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' = {
'Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions@2015-11-01-preview' =
'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/linkedServices@2020-08-01' = {

```
param parPcLawSolutions array = [   
'AzureActivity'
'ChangeTracking'
'Security'

 ]``
```

I am trying idempotent deployment to ignore the resource if it already exists instead of throwing an error.
I could deploy with -mode complete but it will overwrite all other resource too

Comment: could you share the related bicep file please ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you provided, there appears to be a conflict in the resource plan for a specific resource that you are trying to deploy.

This can happen when there is a mismatch between the resource's current state and the desired state that you are attempting to deploy.

And as per this [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep.md), you cannot change the resource plan for a resource that has already been deployed.

In this case, you can write a deployment script as detailed in [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep.md#sample-bicep-files), so that it will create the resource only if it does not exist and it will not cause any system causes.

As detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/resource-manager-workspace?tabs=bicep#template-file), I created a sample template to create a log analytics workspace, deployed in a new resource plan and it worked for me as expected.

```bash
resource  workspace  'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2021-12-01-preview' = {
name: "myws"
location: location
properties: {
sku: {
name: "Standard"
}
retentionInDays: 30
features: {
enableLogAccessUsingOnlyResourcePermissions: true
}
}
}
```

**Note**: I would suggest you create any resource in a separate deployments/resource plans to avoid conflicts.

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

*Workspace created in portal after deployment:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer, logically you explanation make sense. I will give it a try.